# When I am using Dmax, it cannot find the input table

Tags: ms-access

I have a data table called `Proforma Invoice Table` under the Data Table custom label.

When I use `Dmax`, and reference that table, I get an error

> The Microsoft Access database Engine cannot find the input table or
> query "Proforma_Invoice_Table"

```
me.ble = Dmax("proforma_Invoice_number, "Proforma_Invoice_Table")
```

Comment: Posted expression shows missing a quote mark that that would generate a different error message. Are you sure about the table name spelling? Does it really have underscore characters?

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets, not underscores, for table and field names with spaces:

```
Me!Ble = DMax("[Proforma Invoice Number]", "[Proforma Invoice Table]")
```